# Sending JMS messages in a Spring WebFlux reactive handler: is it blocking?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Is this the correct way to handle reactively? I see 2 threads one reactive nio which is until and including `flatMap(fareRepo::save)`. The other thread is computations thread which starts from sending message and goes on till ServerResponse.build(). My question is this correct way to handle request reactively? Note: that fareRepo is reactive couchbase repo.
thanks

```
return request.bodyToMono(Fare.class).flatMap(fareRepo::save).flatMap(fs -> {
            logger.info("sending message: {}, to queue", fs.getId());
            jmsTemplate.send("fare-request-queue", (session) -> session.createTextMessage(fs.getId()));
            return Mono.just(fs);
        }).flatMap(fi -> ServerResponse.created(URI.create("/fare/" + fi.getId())).build());
```

Comment: Your question is off-topic because it is opinion-based primarily but this `fareRepo::save` is probably synchronous operation, so you kinda mixing non-blocking stuff and the blocking one. I would say it is not a good practice.

Comment: @john , forgot to mention that fareRepo is also reactive.

Comment: @jzqa mention is not needed as you're calling `flatMap` :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using Spring Framework's `JmsTemplate` implementation, which is blocking.

Without more context, we can only assume that you have a blocking operation in the middle of a reactive operator and that this will cause issues in your application.

Comment: Assuming this is the case, I found that a (bad) alternative is to call `.block()` at the end of the reactive stream, but of course this defeats the purpose of using WebFlux

Answer (score 4):

Spring JmsTemplate will block your request thread which is not good for reactive design coding. you can try with **.publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())** which will create new thread and execute code without blocking request thread. since it is I/O bound operation use Schedulers.elastic()

```
return request.bodyToMono(Fare.class).flatMap(fareRepo::save)
.publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
.flatMap(fs -> {
            logger.info("sending message: {}, to queue", fs.getId());
            jmsTemplate.send("fare-request-queue", (session) -> session.createTextMessage(fs.getId()));
            return Mono.just(fs);
        }).flatMap(fi -> ServerResponse.created(URI.create("/fare/" + fi.getId())).build());
```